# split string into 3 parts, the middle starts and ends with alphacharacter from A to z

Tags: php, string, preg-match

```
$str="&%*&^h-e_l_lo*&^*&";
```

How to split it into

```
$left="&%*&^";//until the first A-Za-z character
$right="*&^*&";//right after the last A-Za-z character
$middle = "h-e_l_lo";
```

I've found this way to find the $left, but I doubt it is the best way:

```
$curr_word = "&%*&^h-e_l_lo*&^*&";
preg_match('~[a-z]~i', $curr_word, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$left = substr($curr_word, 0,$match[0][1]);// &%*&^
```

Comment: In the string `h-e_l_lo`, `-` and `_` aren't alpha characters. What do you want to match exactly?

Comment: //until the first A-Za-z character
//right after the last A-Za-z character
That were the comments in my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
/([^a-zA-Z]*)(.*[a-zA-Z])(.*)/
```

**Explanation**

`[^a-zA-Z]*` Selects everything until it reaches a letter

`.*[a-zA-Z]` Selects everything until it reaches the last letter

`.*` Selects the remainder of the string

**Example Use**

```
$string = "&%*&^h-e_l_lo*&^*&";
preg_match('/([^a-zA-Z]*)(.*[a-zA-Z])(.*)/', $string, $matches);

echo $matches[1]; // Results in: &%*&^
echo $matches[2]; // Results in: h-e_l_lo
echo $matches[3]; // Results in: &^*&
```